# How to change the Android theme xml in code?

Tags: android, styles, themes

How to change the Android theme xml in code?

I'm want setting the theme xml, change in code.

If not want you to just change color.

before >

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

change xml in code.

after >

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFF00</item>
</style>
```

Comment: They're both the same...

Comment: You should create the custom theme for that]